# Error while dynamically loading mapi32.dll

Tags: delphi, api, dll, mapi, access-denied

Our application uses Simple MAPI to send e-mails. One of our clients has problems sending e-mail from a session on his terminal server.

The mapi32.dll is loaded with a call to LoadLibrary which succeeds, but then our application tries to get the addresses of the functions `MAPILogon`, `MAPILogOff`, `MAPISendMail`, `MAPIFreeBuffer` and `MAPIResolveName`. The problem is that `GetProcAddress` fails for those functions with an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (code: 5) except for `MAPIFreeBuffer`. It looks like some sort of security thing.

How can I fix this or should I use another method to send mail?

FWI, here some more information about OS and contents of registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem:

```
OS info: 5.2.3790 VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT Service Pack 2

Contents of SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem
InstallCmd: rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection MSMAIL 132 msmail.inf
MAPI: 1
CMCDLLNAME: mapi.dll
CMCDLLNAME32: mapi32.dll
CMC: 1
MAPIX: 1
MAPIXVER: 1.0.0.1
OLEMessaging: 1
Contents of SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem\MSMapiApps
inetsw95.exe: 
choosusr.dll: 
msab32.dll:
nwab32.dll:
outstore.dll: Microsoft Outlook
CDOEXM.DLL:
EMSMDB32.DLL:
EMSABP32.DLL:
newprof.exe: Microsoft Outlook
outlook.exe: 
wfxmsrvr.exe: Microsoft Outlook
msexcimc.exe:
exchng32.exe:
schdmapi.dll: Microsoft Outlook
pilotcfg.exe: Microsoft Outlook
mailmig.exe: Microsoft Outlook
admin.exe:
msspc32.dll: Microsoft Outlook
cnfnot32.exe: Microsoft Outlook
ilpilot.exe: Microsoft Outlook
events.exe:
```

I'm on Delphi 7.0, but that shouldn't matter.

**Edit, added version information:**

Fileversion info of C:\WINDOWS\system32\mapi32.dll

```
Fileversion: 6.5.7226.0
FileDescription=Extended MAPI 1.0 for Windows NT
CompanyName=Microsoft Corporation
InternalName=MAPI32
Comments=Service Pack 1
LegalCopyRight=Copyright (C) 1986-2003 Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
LegalTradeMarks=Microsoft(R) and Windows(R) are registered trademarks of Microsoft Corporation.
OriginalFileName=MAPI32.DLL
ProductName=Microsoft Exchange
ProductVersion=6.5
```

Fileversion info of C:\Program Files\Common Files\SYSTEM\MSMAPI\1043\msmapi32.dll

```
Fileversion: 11.0.5601.0
FileDescription=Extended MAPI 1.0 for Windows NT
CompanyName=Microsoft Corporation
InternalName=MAPI32.DLL
LegalCopyRight=Copyright © 1995-2003 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
OriginalFileName=MAPI32.DLL
ProductName=MAPI32
ProductVersion=11.0.5601
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. As you can see in my question the mapi32.dll is provided by Exchange server. ([Version 6.5.7226 = Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 SP1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310111325/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/158530)). According to [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025075832/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2004/07/03/172257.aspx)
Exchange 2003 does not support Simple MAPI for security reasons:

> As of Exchange 2003, Exchange no longer implements Simple MAPI. The API was removed to reduce the potential attack surface

So that is the reason I cannot get the ProcAddresses of the Simple MAPI calls.

It looks like I have to go support Extended MAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of mixed versions of mapi32.dll.  Such as maybe Office2003 and 2007 on the same machine, or a botched uninstall/re-install crossing versions (i.e. tried to uninstall 2007 and go back to 2003, or vice-versa).  Have the client search the entire HD for mapi32.dll and see if there are multiple versions. If there's only one, compare the version to a known, working system.

See this:
http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-outlook/391309-mapi32-dll-error-help-my-kids-xms-gift-broken.html

Comment: I added the requested version information. I have to say that the version of mapi32.dll looks suspicious. Shouldn't that be a stub with version 1, like on Windows XP? Maybe I have to ask my client to run fixmapi.exe.