# Members of MSMAPI namespace greyed out?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

[image: Greyed out classes]

I'm getting no errors in my syntax and I'm getting a System.MissingMemberException thrown at me, and I'm not sure why MAPIMessagesClass is greyed out and I believe this is causing the issue I'm having. Is this an issue with my references?

Thank you !

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmemberexception(v=vs.110).aspx: "there is an attempt to dynamically access a class member that does not exist or that is not declared as public. If a member in a class library has been removed or renamed, recompile any assemblies that reference that library."
Are those members not public? What info do you get if you click on the greyed out members?

Comment: I can view all the members within MAPIMessagesClass for example, and they are all Public Overridable Properties

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but from what I can tell from http://stackoverflow.com/q/2788093/2953322 this seems to be a really old, possibly unsupported library. Where did you get the dlls from?